# addEventListener() not adding to div, but instead firing on initiation

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make a function, that when called adds an event listener to a different div. It's weird that this is the first time I have encountered this problem, as I have done similar things before ...

Anyway, I've isolated the issue, and have wrote this small script to show the problem:

```
<script>
function setNewClickEvent() {
    secondButton=document.getElementById('secondButton');
    secondButton.addEventListener('mouseup',outputHi());
}
function outputHi() {
    console.log('Hi');
}
</script>

<DIV id="firstButton" onclick="setNewClickEvent()" style="width:20px;height:20px;border:1px solid #000000;">
1
</DIV>

<DIV id="secondButton" style="width:20px;height:20px;border:1px solid #000000;">
2
</DIV>
```

The way I want it to work, is when `firstButton` is clicked, it adds the `addEventListener` to the `secondButton`, so that when the `secondButton` is cliicked, it runs the function `outputHi()`.

But, instead of doing this, it runs `outputHi()` when `firstButton` is clicked, and doesn't even add the the event listener to `secondButton`.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Change `secondButton.addEventListener('mouseup',outputHi());` to `secondButton.addEventListener('mouseup',outputHi);` or `secondButton.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){outputHi()});`. You're invoking the function the way you have it now.

Comment: It's because you're **calling** the handler function in the `addEventListener()` parameter list. Get rid of the `()` after the function name so it's just `outputHi` and not `outputHi()`.

Comment: Hahahaha ... Oh yeah ... Hmm ... Well ... Now I feel stupid ... It was driving me crazy Lol

Comment: Ohhh ... Wait a min ... So how can you add an eventListener that uses parameters in the function?

Comment: See my second example.

Comment: Yep, just figured that out ... all by myself :D ... Go me! ... Lol, thanks everyone, and hopefully this helps someone in the future :D

Answer (score 1):

The listener you are adding is the *output* of the function because you are executing it when you add the listener. What you want is adding the function itself as the listener, not its output. So:

```
secondButton.addEventListener('mouseup', outputHi);
```

(notice the lack of `()` after the function)